# how to use submitted data cformsll plugin in wordpress and store separately in database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am using cformsll http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/ plugin and created a contact form (name='Polling Form') and inserted it into a **Polling** page

```
<!--cforms name="Polling Form"-->
```

and for displaying the data I write the code on **Polling** Page as below

```
<!--cforms name="Polling Form"-->

<?php
$array = get_cforms_entries();   /* all data, no filters */

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Website</th></tr>';
foreach( $array as $e ){
    echo '<tr><td>' . $e['data']['Your Name'] . '</td><td>' . $e['data']['Email'] . '</td><td>' . $e['data']['Website'] . '</td><tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

but when I submit the page nothing is happened and the warning is coming

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-test\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 8
```

I searched lots of forums but not able to get its answer how to use submitted data and store separately in database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a variation of the code you have there now, and it works fine. I think the problem you have is that you're trying to use a 2 year old unmaintained plugin to execute PHP on page:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/

You need to take your code out into your theme's functions file, and create a shortcode, like so:

```
function mydatadisplay {
$array = get_cforms_entries();   /* all data, no filters */

/* CHECK TO SEE IF YOU HAVE DATA. Otherwise, your script may fail */
if (! $array) {echo '<p>Query returned no results.</p>'; } else {

/* OK, we have data, so let's display it */

echo '<table>';

echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Website</th></tr>';

foreach( $array as $e ){
echo '<tr><td>' . $e['data']['Your Name'] . '</td><td>' . $e['data']['Email'] . '</td>        <td>' . $e['data']['Website'] . '</td><tr>';}

echo '</table>'; }
}

add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'mydatadisplay');
```

Then call the shortcode in your page:

```
[myshortcode]
```